# Cut beggining and end of string in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
test_b0e0bef67-6f0bc-4efb2c-9fee58-a1ffe.pdf
```

How can I  cut string into pieces and form an array like so:

```
['test', 'b0e0bef67-6f0bc-4efb2c-9fee58-a1ffe', 'pdf']
```

This is one possible solution but I believe this is not the most elegant.

```
const firstPart = string2.split('_');
const secondPart = first[1].split('.');
const result = firstPart.concat(secondPart);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use RegEx `/[_.]/`:

```js
var string2 = 'test_b0e0bef67-6f0bc-4efb2c-9fee58-a1ffe.pdf'

const result = string2.split(/[_.]/);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The `/g` flag is useless.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `([^_]+)_([^.]+)\.(.+)` to:

- `([^_]+)` - Match and capture non-`_`s
- `_` - Match a `_`
- `([^.]+)` - Match and capture non-`.`s
- `\.` - Match a `.`
- `(.+)` - Match and capture anything

```js
const [, ...arr] = 'test_b0e0bef67-6f0bc-4efb2c-9fee58-a1ffe.pdf'.match(/([^_]+)_([^.]+)\.(.+)/);
console.log(arr);
```